# problem in imagemagick and grails

Tags: macos, grails, imagemagick

i have a new problem in image magick that look strange .. 
i'm using mac osx snow leopard and i've installed image magick on it and it's working fine on command .. 
but when i call it from the grails class like the following snippet it gives me 
"Cannot run program "convert": error=2, No such file or directory"

the code is :-

```
 public static boolean resizeImage(String srcPath, String destPath,String size) {

    ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>(10);


    command.add("convert");
    command.add("-geometry");
    command.add(size);
    command.add("-quality");
    command.add("100" );
    command.add(srcPath);
    command.add(destPath);

    System.out.println(command);

    return exec((String[])command.toArray(new String[1]));
}

private static boolean exec(String[] command) {
    Process proc;

    try {
        //System.out.println("Trying to execute command " + Arrays.asList(command));
        proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException while trying to execute " );
        for(int i =0 ; i<command.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(command[i]);
        }
        return false;
    }

    //System.out.println("Got process object, waiting to return.");

    int exitStatus;

    while (true) {
        try {
            exitStatus = proc.waitFor();
            break;
        } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted: Ignoring and waiting");
        }
    }
    if (exitStatus != 0) {
        System.out.println("Error executing command: " + exitStatus);
    }
    return (exitStatus == 0);
}
```

i've tried normal command like ls and it's ok so the problem is that grails can't find convert command itself.. is it a os problem or something?

Answer (score 1):

(see lower for the answer)

I have run into the same problem.  The issue appears to be something with Mac OS X specifically, as we have several Linux instances running without error.  The error looks similar to the following:

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/ImageMagick-6.7.3/bin/convert /a/temp/in/tmpPic3143119797006817740.png /a/temp/out/100000726.png": error=2, No such file or directory

All the files are there, and in chmod 777 directories - and as you pointed out, running the exact command from the shell works fine.

My theory at this point is that imagemgick can not load some sort of library itself, and the "no such file" is in reference to an dylib or something along those lines.

I have tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH and a few others to no avail.

---

I finally got this working. Here is how I have it setup. I hope this helps.

The crux of the fix, for me, was I wrapped the 'convert' into a shell script, set a bunch of environment variables, and then call that shell script instead of convert directly:

(convertWrapper.sh)

```
export MAGICK_HOME=/usr/local/ImageMagick-6.7.5
export MAGICK_CONFIGURE_PATH=${MAGICK_HOME}/etc/ImageMagick:${MAGICK_HOME}/share/doc/ImageMagick/www/source

export PATH=${PATH}:${MAGICK_HOME}/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${MAGICK_HOME}/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${MAGICK_HOME}/lib
export MAGICK_TMPDIR=/private/tmp

echo "$@" >> /private/tmp/m.log 2>&1
/usr/local/ImageMagick-6.7.5/bin/convert -verbose "$@" >> /private/tmp/m.log 2>&1
```

(convertWrapper.sh)

Additionally, the convert call was doing some rather complicated stuff, so I added the parameter '-respect-parenthesis' (which may or may not have had an effect).

I am not sure how much of the environment variable setting is needed as I was stabbing in the dark for a while, but since this is only for my development box...

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out what your PATH is set to when you run a command from Java. It must be different to the one you have when running from the terminal.

Are you running Grails (via Tomcat?) as a different user? It might have a different path to your normal user.

Comment: I'm using netbeans so it's using jetty i suppose.. so what can i do

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try one of the Image Plugins that are part of the grails ecosystem

http://www.grails.org/ImageTools+plugin

the grails path when the app is running in the server is probably different from running java from the command line

Comment: i've tried it and that's why i need image magick.. the quality isn't so good and the options isn't like image magick

Comment: i found the same problem so I just utilize the underlying jai libraries and created my own service

Comment: this might resolve some of your problems http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmagick/

Comment: jmagick is a very strange wrapper.. and i just couldn't find a tutorial that can help me installing it correctly in grails project on my mac

Answer (score 0):

I do so:

Put "convert" file to /usr/bin

Then add to Config.groovy:

```
gk {
    imageMagickPath = "/usr/bin/convert"
}
```

Then in my ImageService.groovy:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder as RCH
```

[..]

```
def grailsApplication = RCH.requestAttributes.servletContext.grailsApplication
def imPath = grailsApplication.config.gk.imageMagickPath
def command = imPath + " some_properties"
def proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)
```

So this way you get command like: /usr/bin/convert some_properties

And it works, but don't forget to put file "convert" to you location and use it with this location.